# How to animate different parts of the same mesh object

Tags: animation

[image]

This object is all one mesh. I want to animate this so that it's rotating horizontally whilst having several of the eyelids blink - the top and bottom eyelids will just be scaled up and down. I can't work out how to create multiple animations for the same mesh. thanks.

Comment: I think [a rig](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/armatures/introduction.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Tutorial ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvG39bGEsKI

Answer (score 1):

Hee very nice idea!

There are a few options here.

First of all, you could rig the mesh with an armature. This might be a bit time consuming.

Also you could try and hook every eyelid with a hook modifier. But this will get messy very quickly. You'd have to parent all the hook empties back to a master that controls the rotation of the whole mesh.

Lastly, this is what I would do in your case. You say it's just a matter of scaling the eye lids, make shape keys for every seperate animation and build up a shape key library if you will. Every think you want to be able to control should be a unique shape key. The shape keys should 'add up' to each other.

Hope this is helpfull, if you have any questions you can contact me.

Ciao,

Mv.artz

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a material that has transparency as a mix factor, and use an Empty on a path constraint as the object in texture coordinates, and maybe rotate the camera around the object.
 Note that the object empty is keyframed at one frame after the animation ends, this is important for a smooth animation.
This is very rough I would encourage you to experiment with the math nodes to better tune it.
Also the scale and rotation of the bezier circle effects the speed of transitions.[image: bezierTransparencyDrive]